# How to write a remove method with Cyclic Doubly-Linked-List with Generic Nodes in Java

Tags: java, generics, nodes, doubly-linked-list, remove-method

I am implementing a cyclic DoublyLinkedList data structure. Like a singly
linked list, nodes in a doubly linked list have a reference to the next node, but unlike a singly linked list, nodes in a doubly linked list also have a reference to the previous node. Additionally, because the list is "cyclic", the "next" reference in the last node in the list points to the first node in the list, and the "prev" reference in the first node in the list points to the last node in the list.

I am having trouble with my remove method with some size usage. It's the message I'm getting when I run my tests.

Here's my code:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<E>
{
private Node first;
private int size;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void add(E value)
{
    if (first == null)
    {
        first = new Node(value, null, null);
        first.next = first;
        first.prev = first;
    }
    else
        {
        first.prev.next = new Node(value, first, first.prev);
        first.prev = first.prev.next;
    }
    size++;
}
private class Node<E>
{
    private E data;
    private Node next;
    private Node prev;

    public Node(E data, Node next, Node prev)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void add(int index, E value)
{
    if (first.data == null)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } else if (index == 0)
    {
        first = new Node(value, first.next, first.prev);
    }
    else
        {
        Node current = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
        {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new Node(value, current.next, current.prev);
    }
}
```

Here is the method I need help with. 
The remove method should remove the element at the specified index in the list. Be sure to address the case in which the list is empty and/or the removed element is the first in the list. If the index parameter is invalid, an IndexOutOfBoundsException should be thrown.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void remove(int index)
{
    if (first.data == null)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    else if (index == 0)
    {
        first = first.next;
    }
    else
        {
            Node current = first.next;
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
        {
            current = current.next;
        }--size;
            current.next = current.next.next;

    }
}
```

Here is the rest of the code. The get method is incorrect, but I asked that in a different question.

```
    public E get(int index)
    {
   if(index >= size)
    {

    }
    return null;
    //return first.data;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public int indexOf(E value)
{
    int index = 0;
    Node current = first;
    while (current != current.next)
    {
        if (current.data.equals(value))
        {
            return index;
        }
        index++;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return index;
}
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        {
        return false;
    }
}
public int size()
{
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Check out my other methods, I'm struggling with them too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228367/how-to-write-a-tostring-method-using-nodes-in-java

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55214062/how-to-create-a-get-method-with-nodes-off-a-generic-type-in-java

Comment: Your method is half-way there, but you aren't updating the reference to the previous node in the list, or handling the last node case correctly. Also think about what needs to happen when there is only one node in the list. I feel you will learn more by working out the correct implementation yourself.

Comment: What would I assign current.prev to then? current.next?

Comment: No, think about it like a chain of people holding hands. To remove someone from the chain you need to tell both the person before and the person after to change who they are holding hands with. Once you have found the node in the list that should be removed, you need to make the next of the node before it point to the node after it. But you also need to go to the node that comes after it and make its previous be the one before the node being removed (current.next.prev = current.prev). While also taking into account the various edge cases (first/last/one entry).

Comment: @MalcolmSmith I see, I will keep working at this and see if I can find a way with this algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not easy at all, however I did find the answer to my question. This is a cyclic doubly linked list. Here it is:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public void remove(int index)
 {
    if(index < 0 || index > size)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    Node n = first;
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        n = n.next;
    }
    // n points to node to remove
    n.prev.next = n.next;
    n.next.prev = n.prev;
    if (index == 0)
    {
        if(size == 1)
        {
            first = null;
        }
        else
        {
            first = first.next;
        }
    }
    size--;
}
```